# How to use the getRange() method with an array value as one of the parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't have much experience using Javascript but I'm developing a simple code to filter some information relevant to a professor I'm helping. I am searching the row number of a certain amount of data using a for and then I'm using an array to store all the rows that contain those words. Since I'm using Appscript, I only need to relocate a certain amount of data from the row I'm returning to a final row I've already know. My code is as follows:

```
 if(cell === "Average")
{
   index++;
   initialcoords[index] = n; // n is the iteration variable in the for
}
```

I've tested the contents of the array and they are just fine, so I'm storing correctly the rows. The problem is that I'm using a different method to paste the data in a different sheet in Google Spreadhsheets. My code to do so is the following:

```
    function pasteInfo()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var source = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
 var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");

  var range = source.getRange(initialcoords[1], 1, 8, 3);
  range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 4, 6, 4, 6);
}
```

My probelm is the getRange() since it prints an error like this:

```
can't find method getRange((class),number,number,number).
```

I believe that even if n is declared as an integer, the values that I'm returning are of a different type incompatible with the getRange() method. Could anyone help me to confirm this and to help me convert it to integer? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: To check your suspicions, try adding a `console.log(typeof initialcoords[1]);`. What does it say?

Comment: Thank you for your help Noumenon, I've try adding this but since I'm using the online editor for google-apps-script it says that console it's not defined, I have used console.log in the past but I don't know any similar command in AppScript

Comment: @DanielLara Google apps script has Logger.log()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

Answer (score 2):

You first need to define the Sheet you want to get the data from since a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) can have multiple Sheets.

You need to ensure you have appropriate default values defined before using the parameters, otherwise the interpreter will start making guess.

Provide defaults if parameters are empty:

```
function fillLine(row, column, length, bgcolor)
{
row = row || 0;
column = column || 0;
length = length || 1;
bgcolor = bgcolor || "red";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1+row, 1+column, 1, length).setBackground(bgcolor)
}
```

You may also try the solution offered by community: [Can't get Google Scripts working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367010/cant-get-google-scripts-working)